# How to call dependency Injection screenshot code in my shared code?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, screenshot

I'm a beginner in Xamarin.Forms, and I have a question: How can I call the following code in my shared code/xaml.cs?

```
public class screenshotManager : IScreenshotManager
{    

    public static Activity Activity { get; set; }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> CaptureAsync()
    {
        if (Activity == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("You have to set ScreenshotManager.Activity in your Android project");
        }

        var view = Activity.Window.DecorView;
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(true);

        byte[] bitmapData;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return bitmapData;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read the docs?  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/

Comment: ive tried to put this code inside a click event  but nothing happened 
 DependencyService.Get<IScreenshotManager>().CaptureAsync();

Comment: Did you registered your implementation? `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (screenshotManager))]` as [docs asks to](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Registration)?

Comment: did it already. nice! thank you, now my problem is how to convert a byte[] into an image.

Comment: convert your byte[] to a stream, then use StreamImageSource

Comment: Maybe you need this plugin: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Screenshot/

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to get the image captured from a byte[], as we discussed in comments, so you should do as @Jason said.

Something like this:

```
var imageBytes = await screenshotManager.CaptureAsync();
Image imageView = new Image();
imageView.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```